# Does removal of domain www prefix require Google address change tool?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search-console

I am aware of the Google webmaster tool for changing addresses, which according to the [help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34437?hl=en&ref_topic=6029673) applies for the following site moves:

- The protocol: `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`
- The domain name: `example.com` to `example.net`
- The URL paths: `example.com/page.php?id=1` to `example.com/widget`

So just to be sure, if I am to change my domain from `www.example.com` to `example.com` a 301 redirect would be sufficient and I do not need the Google site move tool? Or are there people who have bad experiences with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on changing www to non-www, you should do both:

1 make a 301 redirect

2 make a change in the search console

- Without the first you get duplicated content issue
- without the second you get wrong data in the search console and in analytics, if search console bound to it.

Comment: "make a change in the search console" - to be clear, the _change_ in the search console does not involve the "change of address" tool that the OP is asking about, but the "Site Settings" > "Preferred domain" option.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. The combination of answers is perfect.